# Translating “cum chordis corda, cum fidibus fides”

Tags: classical-latin, vocabulary, latin-to-english-translation, translation-explanation

I’m having trouble understanding the following construction:

> cum chordis corda, cum fidibus fides

It is taken from a German manuscript by Dietericus mentioning that the human body should be like a divine pipe organ praising God. At the end he mentions:

> Der Finger in Gottes rechter Hand, der soll mit seinem Finger das
> clavir unseres Hertzens schlagen, solches durch den Wind seiner Worte
> bewegen, damit unser Leib, unsere Füße, unsere Hände, Sinn und
> Gedanken, unsere Affecten und Begierden eine rechte und geistliche,
> liebliche anmuthige Resonanz geben, dadurch *cum chordis corda, cum*
> *fidibus fides*, mit den Seiten clavir und Klange die Hertzen mit dem
> Glauben die Werck zusammen stimmen

A quick translation of the very last part would be:

> cum chordis corda, cum fidibus fides, the hearts should match the sound of the keyboard, and the works should match with the faith

I’m not sure if *chordis* refers to the *hearts* or *strings*.

I’ve been interested in explaining the construction above and its translation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a double pun.

*Cum chordis* means "with the chords" or "with the strings"; *corda* means "the hearts". Similarly, *cum fidibus* means "with the lyre" or "with the strings"; *fides* means "faith".

So literally: **the hearts [should align] with the chords, and the faith [should align] with the strings**. But unfortunately, the pun doesn't translate well at all: *chordis* comes from *chorda* (which looks very similar to *corda*), and *fidibus* comes from *fides* (which looks identical to *fides*).

Comment: For the first part you could render the pun nicely by something like "with the strings move the heartstrings".